# How to solve Gradle Dependency inconsistencies in sub-modules?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

Within my Gradle project I have many different *versions* of the same dependencies.

For example at my top level `gradle build file` I have declared a certain version of a dependency, but the sub-modules have delcared a different version.

Ideally I would like to have have the dependencies declared **once** at the top level so that all modules are using the **same version** of the dependency.

Is it possible to do this so that all sub-modules are using only the dependencies stated in the top level file?

If so, do I just update the top-level dependencies to the latest version and delete the dependencies declared within the sub-modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all your dependencies in a project property in the main build file

```
ext.libraries = [
    commons_io: "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"
  , jasperreports: dependencies.create('net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:5.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.lowagie'
        exclude group: 'jfree'
  }
  , cxf: [
        'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:3.1.4'
      , 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.4']
]
```

and then in the subproject build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile libraries.commons_io
  compile libraries.jasperreports
  compile libraries.cxf
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what is "exclude group" used for in the example above?

Comment: It's a way to exclude transitive dependencies

Comment: Thanks, so there is no dependencies section in the top level build.gradle at all?

Comment: You need to define the dependency version in parent file in < DependencyManagement > so declaration is at one location . and you can use it where ever you wanted to and over there you dont need to declare dependency  and the version is picked up from < DependencyManagement >

Comment: @java123999 yes, that's what I suggested - root project has no depencies

Comment: @Raffaele Thanks, is this a different method than what Jaydatt is suggesting?

Comment: What @Jaydatt suggests [is not available in Gradle](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/maven-style-dependencymanagement/546). In the linked thread, the Gradle authors themselves suggest what I wrote in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Well the simple answer is yes. Maven is also giving similar kind of facility where you should have one parent file where you can declare a < DependencyManagement > block and over there you can define all your dependencies.

Now, every child project or different modules are dependent on this parent project. So, these all modules have to declare dependency without the version, because we have declared this version in < DependencyMangement > block.

So, at the end what we say here is we are declaring the dependency at one location and using it where ever we need it.

Remember here that declaring dependencies in < DependencyManagement > blcok would not actually resolve the dependencies it will just declare it and child modules using < Dependency > can use that w/o defining version.

Comment: Thanks a lot , basically are you describing the code example shown below by rafaelle?

Comment: No, I am not describing that code. I am just describing the general management how it should be.

Comment: I didn't mean that in a negative way, I mean is that the same idea as the other answer? I ask for my own clarity